# How to display the state from one page to another in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have 2 main pages in ReactJS , and I have a submit button and 3 input fields(name project, description,and hours).
Every time I enter values in these inputs, I display them, and also I created a path using routes for each project I enter.
How can I import the state values from the main Page that I entered(name,description and hours) , to display them on the second page?

Thank you in advance!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bIZhq.png)

Comment: Paulus, I'd recommend adding some sample code of your React pages so that we can troubleshoot, show us where your code isn't working and what your desired outcome is.

Comment: There are many ways. You need to be more specific with your question while you ask. For this  question, I would recommend you start learning react from the very beginning.

Answer (score 1):

Change the < a > elements into < Link > react-router elements

---

```
function ListProjects({ projects }) {
  console.log("projects", projects);

  return (
     <div>
     <ul>
      {projects.map((project, index) => {
        return (
          <li key={index} style={{ listStyleType: "none" }}>
           <Link
        to={{
          pathname: `project/${index}`,
          state: project
        }}
            {project.email},{project.description},{project.quantity}
          </Link>
        </li>
      );
    })}
  </ul>
</div>
```

---

and then in Project page use react-router { this.props.location } for reaching the state https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/api/location

Comment: https://github.com/paulus1991/github.io   here is the code until now, what is important to me is to display the value that I entered, to display it on the second page. I tried import props, but I couldn't manage. Thank you

Comment: it seems that your trouble is with react-router import props, editing my answer accords @PaulusEVU